# 16.04 problem with bcmwl-kernel-source package

Tags: 16.04, apt

I've got some problem to do a usual update. The package `bcmwl-kernel-source` cause problem when I executed `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-24-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: bcmwl-kernel-source package processing error (--configure) :
 the installed post-install script subprocess returned a status output error 10
Errors were encountered during execution :
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I executed `sudo apt autoremove` or `sudo apt install -f`, I've got the same thing.

```
uname -a
Linux prynel-desktop 4.15.0-24-generic #26~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 15 14:35:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPDATE:

After executing command from this link [Ubuntu Wifi drivers not working after getting update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037366/ubuntu-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-getting-update), my wireless connection work partially; I've got a connection unstable. I'm using it notably `ssh` and `scp` command to work with an embedded system (which is the Access Point), but the unstable wireless connection cut the pipe

```
[Some file without problem to tranfer]
caffe.pb.h                                    100% 1222KB   1.2MB/s   00:00    
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
lost connection
```

And there a small part of a continous `ping` command on the computer :

```
64 bytes from 192.168.x.x: icmp_seq=1120 ttl=64 time=62.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.x.x: icmp_seq=1121 ttl=64 time=109 ms
From 192.168.x.y icmp_seq=1150 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.x.y icmp_seq=1151 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.x.y icmp_seq=1152 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.x.x: icmp_seq=1156 ttl=64 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.x.x: icmp_seq=1157 ttl=64 time=76.2 ms
```

Comment: I've got the same problem and this post solved it: [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037366/ubuntu-wifi-drivers-not-working-after-getting-update)

Comment: @user846428 that help a little, but the wireless connection isn't stable (will be a temporary solution until next answer)